# Using strsplit wid pipe separator in R

Tags: r

I have a string called line as below.

"2015-07-22|06:43:44+0000|37e86ffa-dd28-450d-aa9a-3d6776a31337|dummy|t1|USA-4DTV-DEFAULT|USA|MV000375100000|Striking Distance|MOVIE|TMS|VIEWED_MOVIE|NA|NA|NA|NA|**"

I am trying to split it on the separator "|", as :

```
strsplit(line, "|")
```

But the output is a s below :

```
  [1] "2" "0" "1" "5" "-" "0" "7" "-" "2" "2" "|" "0" "6" ":" "4" "3" ":"
 [18] "4" "4" "+" "0" "0" "0" "0" "|" "3" "7" "e" "8" "6" "f" "f" "a" "-"
 [35] "d" "d" "2" "8" "-" "4" "5" "0" "d" "-" "a" "a" "9" "a" "-" "3" "d"
 [52] "6" "7" "7" "6" "a" "3" "1" "3" "3" "7" "|" "d" "u" "m" "m" "y" "|"
 [69] "t" "1" "|" "U" "S" "A" "-" "4" "D" "T" "V" "-" "D" "E" "F" "A" "U"
 [86] "L" "T" "|" "U" "S" "A" "|" "M" "V" "0" "0" "0" "3" "7" "5" "1" "0"
[103] "0" "0" "0" "0" "|" "S" "t" "r" "i" "k" "i" "n" "g" " " "D" "i" "s"
[120] "t" "a" "n" "c" "e" "|" "M" "O" "V" "I" "E" "|" "T" "M" "S" "|" "V"
[137] "I" "E" "W" "E" "D" "_" "M" "O" "V" "I" "E" "|" "N" "A" "|" "N" "A"
[154] "|" "N" "A" "|" "N" "A" "|" "*" "*"
```

It is not even recognizing the pipe separators.

Comment: How about `strsplit(line, "\\|")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needs to add to backslash before the bar:

```
strsplit(x, "\\|")
```

For example:

```
> x <- "Hello | Could you help me please?"
> strsplit(x, "\\|")
[[1]]
[1] "Hello "                     " Could you help me please?"
```

Comment: better to use `sep = '|', fixed = TRUE` -- code is clearer to read, and it will be faster as well

Comment: yes, tested that and it's about 3x quicker - thanks